# Mulitple ng-views, I want to reload only 1 ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following:

```
.state('a.abc',{
    url: '/abc', 
    views : { 
        wizards : { 
            templateUrl : 'abcLeft.html', }, 
        contentDetails : { 
            templateUrl : 'abcRight.html', } } })

.state('a.abc.add',{ 
    url: '/add', 
    views : { 
        wizards : { 
            templateUrl : 'abcAddLeft.html', }, 
        contentDetails : { 
            templateUrl : 'abcRight.html', } } })
```

A - main UI view.

B - under A (left side). It has list of all items.

C - under A (right side). The above same list but with different format and additional data is displayed

A,B,C are ui views in hierarchy mentioned above.

Both B and C views have 'Add new' and 'Edit' button. On click of those, I navigate to state by which left side div is replaced with Add/Edit div.Note that right div still remains the same, which has detailed listing of items.So, for right side, I gave the same template URL. But it still reloads the right div too.

I cannot make right side div as abstract, since its not parent to left div.

Comment: can you show the code for your `$stateProvider`? it's impossible to tell you how to structure your states with no code.  For example, are you using the views property on your states?

Comment: .state('a.abc',{
    url: '/abc',
    views : {
     wizards : {
      templateUrl : 'abcLeft.html',
     },
     contentDetails : {
     templateUrl : 'abcRight.html',
     }
    }
      })

Comment: And when I click on Add/Edit button which on abcRight.html, this state is triggered                                                                                                              .state('a.abc.add',{
    url: '/add',
    views : {
     wizards : {
      templateUrl : 'abcAddLeft.html',
     },
     contentDetails : {
     templateUrl : 'abcRight.html',
     }
    }
      })

Comment: please edit your question when adding code in the future.  it's impossible to read code that has been pasted into a comment.  I'm adding your code to the question for you.

Comment: Perhaps a jsfiddle would help people help you.